# Prawn and Pdf-Toolkit Save file to Public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

I have an rails 5.2 app and its about generating a pdf files.

I am using pdf doc as template and generating new temp pdf and with pdf-toolkit doing merging of these two to a final pdf  file.

This are file paths in development:

```
template_file = File.join(Rails.root, "lib/ams1035.pdf")
prawn_file = File.join(Rails.root, "lib/temp.pdf") 
output_file = File.join(Rails.root, "public/pdfs/ams1035-#{@income.id}.pdf")
```

and this are on production server:

```
template_file: /home/deploy/ss.info/releases/20180808154901/lib/ams1035.pdf

prawn_file: /home/deploy/ss.info/releases/20180808154901/lib/temp.pdf

output_file: /home/deploy/ss.info/releases/20180808154901/public/pdfs/ams1035-2.pdf
```

Locally in development on button click pds is generated and created in `public/pdfs/`  but on production never seeing any pdf file is generated. 
If I upload manually file on location, click opens pdf correctly.

Questio: do I missing something or do I need to add some permissions to `public/pdfs`  folder for prawn/pdf-toolkit so they can create file on location?

Comment: Any errors in any logs? Is pdf-toolkit installed on the production server?

Comment: Only error in production.log is : ActionController::MissingFile (Cannot read file /home/deploy/ss.info/releases/20180808154901/public/pdfs/ams1035-2.pdf):  dont see any other errors about prawn installation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was I need it to install pdftk manually on my server Ubuntu 16.04.
Logged on with ssh and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

Instructed from: https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/pdftk